# Emberjs Updates/Observers/Run Loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller which observes a property (array), and every time it changes, calls an expensive function on the server, then displays the result.

In the initial controller setup (in the route), I need to loop through the array and set some of the values - i.e.

`something.forEach(function(el) { myArrayProperty.set(el.id, true); });`

This is firing the observer on every loop through the `forEach`.  How can I loop through the `forEach`, update all the elements, and **THEN** allow the Ember observer to fire?

I've tried `scheduleOnce` and `Ember.run(function() {..})` but I can't quite seem to get it working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of tackling this problem is to throttle or debounce the expensive function(s) that observe the array.

See [Ember.run.debounce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce)

E.g. you have this now:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  myExpensiveObserver: function() {
    /* some expensive computations */
  }.observes('content.@each.id'),
});
```

... and you change that to this instead:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  myExpensiveObserver: function() {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.myExpensiveObserverImpl, 300);
  }.observes('content.@each.id'),
  myExpensiveObserverImpl: function() {
     /* some expensive computations */
  },
});
```

(replace `300` with the minumum interval you want between recomputations.)

There is a subtle difference between 
[Ember.run.debounce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce)
and [Ember.run.throttle](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_throttle),
and you might prefer one of them over the other.
However, from your description, it sounds like either one could fit the bill.

As pointed out by @kingpin2k, be careful with the function you pass in to debounce or throttle.
It cannot be anonymous, as Ember will not be able to determine whether they were indeed the same each time it is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried this out, and it is working exactly as I had hoped! I was thinking there might have been a `Ember.PAUSE_ALL_THE_THINGS!` and `Ember.RESTART_ALL_THE_THINGS!` functionality, but this works just fine.

Comment: bguiz, will you fix your debounce call please, then I'll gladly upvote this.

Comment: @kingpin2k You're right, thanks for pointing this out. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

bguiz is totally right, throttle or debounce it.  Throttling will allow it to run every x milliseconds, and debounce will block it from running until it hasn't run for x milliseconds.  One small nuance that was missed in the other answer is the way Ember keeps track of the debounces/throttles is by the comparing the passed in function.  So passing in an anonymous function each time will just keep firing without throttling/debouncing.

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  myExpensiveObserver: function() {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.realWorker, 300);
  }.observes('content.@each.id'),
  realWorker: function(){
    console.log("I'm working");
  },
  myExpensiveObserverThrottle: function() {
    Ember.run.throttle(this, this.realWorkerThrottle, 300);
  }.observes('content.@each.id'),
  realWorkerThrottle: function(){
    console.log("I'm working");
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cixawagi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I've accepted the other answer, but this information was very helpful.